# Drupal 7 to 9 migration - how to customize the migration yml generated by migrate-upgrade

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drush

Am trying to customize migrations so that i can map the data to specific fields but after i edit files am not able to place then to active configuration successfully.

My process so far

how i generated the files

Step 1. Generation of migration files

```
drush migrate:upgrade --legacy-db-key=migrate --legacy-root=http://localhost/drupal7 --configure-only
```

Step 2. Creation of a custom module

```
modules/custom/my_custom_migrations
```

inside i have config/install folder

Step 3. Exporting the migrations created to my module

```
drush cex --destination=/Users/mac/Sites/drupal9/web/modules/custom/my_custom_migrations/config/install
```

Step 4. I modified the yml files then tried the following import stript

```
drush cim —source=/Users/mac/Sites/drupal9/web/modules/custom/my_custom_migrations/config/install
```

this deleted all my migrations on the active configuration and never updated with my customized ones

Step 5. I then added the my_custom_migrations.info.yml in the custom module and run

```
drush en my_custom_migrations -y
```

this created my migrations in the active configuration but i got and error when trying `drush ms`

part of error

```
[error]  TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration::getProcessNormalized() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Users/mac/Sites/drupal9/web/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php on line 706 in Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration->getProcessNormalized() (line 451 of /Users/mac/Sites/drupal9/web/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php) #0 /Users/mac/Sites/drupal9/web/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php(706): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration->getProcessNormalized(NULL)
```

How can i either fix the error or make the `drush cim` to work as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured how to update the migrations in the active configuration

Step 1. Config export everything to a folder in my case i added a tmp folder in config in my custom module

```
drush cex --destination=/Users/mac/Sites/drupal9/web/modules/custom/my_custom_migrations/config/install
```

Step 2. Edit the yml files that you want then run the Config import status which will only import the migrations that have changes to your active configuration

```
drush cim status --source=/Users/mac/Sites/drupal9/web/modules/custom/my_custom_migrations/config/tmp
```